# Project Euler # 44 Pentagon numbers in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

> Pentagonal numbers are generated by the formula, \$P_n=\frac{n(3n−1)}{2}\$. The first ten pentagonal numbers are:
>
> `1, 5, 12, 22, 35, 51, 70, 92, 117, 145`
>
> It can be seen that \$P_4 + P_7 = 22 + 70 = 92 = P_8\$. However, their difference, \$70 − 22 = 48\$, is not pentagonal.
>
> Find the pair of pentagonal numbers, \$P_j\$ and \$P_k\$, for which their sum and difference are pentagonal and \$D = |P_k − P_j|\$ is minimised; what is the value of D?

Awaiting feedback.

```
from time import time


def generate_pentagons(n):
    """generates next n pentagons"""
    pentagons = (num * (3 * num - 1) // 2 for num in range(1, n))
    for i in range(n - 1):
        yield next(pentagons)


def get_pentagons(n):
    """Assumes n is a range > 0.
    generates pentagons that obey to the + - rules."""
    pentagons = set(generate_pentagons(n))
    for pentagon1 in pentagons:
        for pentagon2 in pentagons:
            if pentagon1 + pentagon2 in pentagons and abs(pentagon1 - pentagon2) in pentagons:
                return pentagon1, pentagon2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time()
    pent1, pent2 = get_pentagons(10000)
    print(abs(pent1 - pent2))
    print(f'Time: {time() - start_time} seconds.')
```

Comment: Why do you ignore the repeated advice ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224598/project-euler-34-digit-factorials-in-python#comment435654_224598), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224607/project-euler-36-double-base-palindromes-in-python#comment435675_224607)) to tag Python questions correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem to be ignoring your advice but in fact, 'python-3.x' as well as 'programming-challenge' are already tagged. I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: check under the code block, you must see them I guess.

Comment: From the first referenced comment: “Please tag all Python questions with [python], ...”

Comment: You're averaging 5 questions a day. Some of the downvotes might be from people who think you should take things a lot slower, waiting for answers to one question so that you can apply the same principles to your next program.

Comment: @Peter Taylor it's not a big deal man. any feedback given will be helpful that's the whole point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is an answer focused primarily about styling**

- Your parameter names can be renamed to be more specific, like `generate_pentagons(n)` can be rewritten to `generate_pentagons(number_of_pentagons)`. This change can also be implemented in the `get_pentagons` method. While this may seem useless in this program, since `n` can be easily interpreted as the number of pentagons to generate, it's a good practice to follow when you start writing large programs that require more specific parameter names.
- Parameter constants should be UPPERCASE.
- You don't use `i` in your loop in `generate_pentagons` method. To avoid generating an unused variable, you can use an underscore. The `_` immediately signals the reader that the value is not important.

***Final Code***

```
from time import time


def generate_pentagons(number_of_pentagons):
    """generates next n pentagons"""
    pentagons = (num * (3 * num - 1) // 2 for num in range(1, number_of_pentagons))
    for _ in range(number_of_pentagons - 1):
        yield next(pentagons)


def get_pentagons(number_of_pentagons):
    """Assumes n is a range > 0. Generates pentagons that obey to the + - rules."""
    pentagons = set(generate_pentagons(number_of_pentagons))
    for pentagon1 in pentagons:
        for pentagon2 in pentagons:
            if pentagon1 + pentagon2 in pentagons and abs(pentagon1 - pentagon2) in pentagons:
                return pentagon1, pentagon2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    START_TIME = time()
    PENTAGON_1, PENTAGON_2 = get_pentagons(10000)
    print(abs(PENTAGON_1 - PENTAGON_2))
    print(f"Time: {time() - START_TIME} seconds.")
```